# RSS feed reader compatible with arxiv

Tags: rss, rss-reader

Is there any RSS feed reader that is compatible with Arxiv rss feeds which have the annoyance of using html tags for authors? So I want a reader that does not display the author as `<a href="http://arxiv.org/find/quant-ph/1.`.. but rather author's name, I do not really care about the link. I tried outlook, Rssowl, various plugins chrome extensions but either the extensions are clumsy or they cannot handle the html tags in author. I prefer a program, not some web site rss feed reader.

Answer (score 1):

QuiteRSS is able to parse the information correctly.

Note also that instead of using the url `http://export.arxiv.org/rss/hep-ph` (for example), you can try to use `http://export.arxiv.org/api/query?search_query=(cat:hep-th)&sortBy=lastUpdatedDate&sortOrder=descending&max_results=200`, with the flags adjusted as you desire. Note that I haven't confirmed that the two feed outputs are identical (i.e. nothing falls through the cracks). The second option is just arXiv search results in an RSS-like format

Answer (score 0):

The Vienna RSS reader appears to display the author's name correctly. (Tested with Vienna 3.1.4 on the arxiv.org cs updates feed).

[link to Vienna on github](https://github.com/ViennaRSS/vienna-rss)

Comment: I have just tried it. It does not work for me.  (Tested with Vienna 3.1.14 on the arxiv.org cs updates feed, on an iMac with OS X El Capitan 10.11.6).

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing fine with **feedly**. Although it doesn't evince the problem you describe, it does have the failing that it doesn't interpret LateX. (But no RSS feeder will.)

Answer (score 0):

feeder (f-droid) seems to work with arxiv
spaRSS fails